# Unable to automatically install go extensions in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, package

I am getting started with Go and would like to use Visual Studio Code for editing. I successfully installed go on my Ubuntu Computer.

My `GOPATH` (go env) is set to the same value as `go.gopath` in settings.json. If I run `Go: Current GOPATH` it outputs the correct path.

However, I am not able to install the go extensions. If I click on `Install all` I get output similar to this:

```
Installing 1 tool at home/jan/go/bin
  dlv

Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv FAILED

1 tools failed to install.

dlv:
Error: Command failed: /snap/bin/go get -u -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

I seem to be able to just install packages manually with `/snap/bin/go get -u -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv`. The command runs without errors, but VSCode seems to be unable to find dlv.

My settings.json:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "dom",
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.formatTool": "gofmt",
    "go.lintOnSave": "file",
    "go.vetOnSave": "package",
    "go.buildOnSave": "package",
    "go.lintTool": "golint",
    "go.gopath": "home/jan/go"
}
```

I have git installed on my computer. It works without a problem.

Comment: Are you using single Workspace? Is it intended to be `$HOME/go`? If answer is Yes for both, you can clean up `$GOPATH` env variable and `go.gopath` in vscode, Go will fall back to `$HOME/go`. Otherwise check if "go.gopath" is actually the same as `$GOPATH`, this path looks strange - `home/jan/go`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your GOPATH is not set correctly in `settings.json`.

```
    "go.gopath": "home/jan/go"
```

This path is relative, and so it would be appended to whatever your working directory is, with the obvious result of not being able to find the path as it won't exist.

You can either set it correctly, or delete it and the GOPATH environment variable will be used. (I run it this way.)

```
    "go.gopath": "/home/jan/go"
```

Comment: Shame on me. That was super obvious